# How can I specify a dataset according to a certain requirement?

Tags: command, regression, stata

I would like to perform a regression on a data set. However, the dataset is very large and includes data from companies over a period from 1989 to 2019. As can be seen in the attached image, the maximum observations per group is 30.
Is it possible to specify the regression command or the data set to use only the maximum number of observations per group. So only for companies where data for 30 years are consistently available?

```
xtreg tobins_q_w rdi_w ivol_w firm_size_log_w industry_q_w growth_w lev_w adi_w os_w, fe
```

[Outcome xtreg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6k1fv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
egen OK = total(!missing(tobins_q_w, rdi_w, ivol_w, firm_size_log_w, industry_q_w, growth_w, lev_w, adi_w, os_)), by(PERMNO)
```

and then regress conditionally on `OK == 30`.